# sshd no longer logging after update on fresh CentOS 7 Install

Tags: ssh, logging, centos7, rsyslog

I am running a VPS with CentOS 7.

After a clean install, I correctly saw failed login attempts and service restarts appearing in `/var/log/secure` like so:

`Jul  8 13:55:32 vps unix_chkpwd[2561]: password check failed for user (root)`

...

`Jul  8 14:03:21 vps sshd[13388]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  8 14:03:21 vps sshd[13388]: Server listening on :: port 22`

After running `sudo yum update`, the logging to `/var/log/secure` suddenly stopped.
However, `journalctl -u sshd` still shows failed login attempts and the restarting of the services.

`rsyslog.conf` has not changed:

```
[midas@vps ~]$ ls -la /etc/rsyslog.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3232  7 sep  2015 /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

and correctly redirects authpriv.* logs to `/var/log/secure`:

```
#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

I actually did the clean install to retrace where this problem was coming from. Any help would be appreciated as I currently have no clue where the logs are being stored apart from the journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `sudo fixfiles restore` and restarting the syslogd afterwards, this worked again for me.

It's a known issue after upgrading CentOS 7 as described in [CentOS 7.0 Release Notes - Known Issues - Security](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/Known-Issues-Security.html)

***policycoreutils component, BZ#1082676***

> Due to a bug in the fixfiles scripts, if the exclude_dirs file is defined to exclude directories from relabeling, running the fixfiles restore command applies incorrect labels on numerous files on the system.